# How can I detect differences of JSON in javascript?

Tags: javascript, json

I'm using gojs library and I have to record which value was modified.(Like Git commit history)

So, I want to compare JSON and detect which key was changed.

Example Original JSON

```
{
  "key01": {
    "key01-01": "val01-01",
    "key01-02": "val01-02"
  },
  "key02": {
    "key02-01": 0
  }
}
```

Example Modified JSON

```
{
  "key01": {
    "key01-01": "val01-01mod"
  },
  "key02": {
    "key02-01": 0,
    "key02-02": 1
    "key02-03": {
      "key02-03-01": 2
    }
  }
}
```

Compare result

```
["key01"]["key01-01"] -> modified
["key01"]["key01-02"] -> removed
["key02"]["key02-02"] -> added
["key02"]["key02-03"] -> added
["key02"]["key02-03"]["key-02-03-01"] -> added
```

Is there a good way to implement this function in javascript?

Comment: Are you trying to determine what changed in the structure?  Or, literally trying to compare the serialized version in JSON text?

Comment: well, first, you want to deal with objects, not JSON - so, parse the JSON to an object - then, it's probably going to need a function written in javascript to do what you want - it'll be quite complex to be honest

Comment: I'm trying to determine structure, not JSON text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can iterate on object and compare them, I did a naive implementation if you want to take this as a starting point:

```js
const isObject = o => o && typeof o === 'object'
const diffObject = (a, b, prefix = []) => {
    const aKeys = Object.keys(a)
    const bKeys = Object.keys(b)
    const diff = []
    for (const key of aKeys) {
        if (a[key] === b[key]) continue
        if (!(key in b)) {
            diff.push({ type: 'removed', key: [...prefix, key] })
            continue
        }
        if (!isObject(a[key]) || !isObject(b[key])) {
            diff.push({ type: 'modified', key: [...prefix, key] })
            continue
        }
        diff.push(...diffObject(a[key], b[key], [...prefix, key]))
    }
    for (const key of bKeys) {
        if (key in a) continue
        diff.push({ type: 'added', key: [...prefix, key] })
        isObject(b[key]) && diff.push(...diffObject({}, b[key], [...prefix, key]))
    }
    return diff
}

// get the diff
const changes = diffObject({
  "key01": {
    "key01-01": "val01-01",
    "key01-02": "val01-02"
  },
  "key02": {
    "key02-01": 0
  }
}, {
  "key01": {
    "key01-01": "val01-01mod"
  },
  "key02": {
    "key02-01": 0,
    "key02-02": 1,
    "key02-03": {
      "key02-03-01": 2
    }
  }
})

// print the diff formated
for (const change of changes) {
    const formatedKey = change.key.map(k => `[${JSON.stringify(k)}]`).join('')
    console.log(formatedKey, '->', change.type)
}
```

One of the tricky part is handeling the depth of the object, I kept it in a `key` array that keeps the history of traversed objects keys.

Answer (score -1):

Affiliation: I am the author of this lib.

How about this: https://eggachecat.github.io/jycm-json-diff-viewer/

You can easily complete your task. More interestingly, if 'key02-02' is something like a 'timestamp' which almost guarantees change, you can ignore this by simply doing a configuration.

[image]

Step by step:

1. install deps

```bash
yarn add jycm
```

2. use the lib

```js
const {
    YouchamaJsonDiffer,
    ListItemFieldMatchOperator,
    make_ignore_order_func
} = require('jycm');

const left = {
  "key01": {
    "key01-01": "val01-01",
    "key01-02": "val01-02"
  },
  "key02": {
    "key02-01": 0
  }
};

const right = {
  "key01": {
    "key01-01": "val01-01mod"
  },
  "key02": {
    "key02-01": 0,
    "key02-02": 1
    "key02-03": {
      "key02-03-01": 2
    }
  }
};

const ycm = new YouchamaJsonDiffer(left, right, {
  "operators": [
  
  ],
  "ignore_orders": [
  ]
});
const diffResult = ycm.get_diff(true);
console.log(diffResult);
```

You can get

```json
{
  "dict:add": [
    {
      "left": "__NON_EXIST__",
      "right": 1,
      "left_path": "",
      "right_path": "key02->key02-02"
    },
    {
      "left": "__NON_EXIST__",
      "right": {
        "key02-03-01": 2
      },
      "left_path": "",
      "right_path": "key02->key02-03"
    }
  ],
  "dict:remove": [
    {
      "left": "val01-02",
      "right": "__NON_EXIST__",
      "left_path": "key01->key01-02",
      "right_path": ""
    }
  ],
  "value_changes": [
    {
      "left": "val01-01",
      "right": "val01-01mod",
      "left_path": "key01->key01-01",
      "right_path": "key01->key01-01",
      "old": "val01-01",
      "new": "val01-01mod"
    }
  ]
}
```

3. make use of the result

```js
function formatKey(record, useLeft) {
  return (useLeft ? record.left_path : record.right_path)
    .split("->")
    .reduce((prev, curr) => `${prev}[${curr}]`);
}

diffResult["value_changes"].map((record) =>
  console.log(`${formatKey(record, true)} -> modified`)
);
diffResult["dict:remove"].map((record) =>
  console.log(`${formatKey(record, true)} -> removed`)
);
diffResult["dict:add"].map((record) =>
  console.log(`${formatKey(record, false)} -> added`)
);
```

Or here's a codesniffet:

```js
const {
  YouchamaJsonDiffer,
  ListItemFieldMatchOperator,
  make_ignore_order_func,
} = jycm;

const left = {
  "key01": {
    "key01-01": "val01-01",
    "key01-02": "val01-02"
  },
  "key02": {
    "key02-01": 0
  }
};

const right = {
  "key01": {
    "key01-01": "val01-01mod"
  },
  "key02": {
    "key02-01": 0,
    "key02-02": 1,
    "key02-03": {
      "key02-03-01": 2
    }
  }
};

const ycm = new YouchamaJsonDiffer(left, right, {
  "operators": [
  
  ],
  "ignore_orders": [
  ]
});

const diffResult = ycm.get_diff(true);


function formatKey(record, useLeft) {
  return (useLeft ? record.left_path : record.right_path)
    .split("->")
    .reduce((prev, curr) => `${prev}["${curr}"]`, "");
}

diffResult["value_changes"].map((record) =>
  console.log(`${formatKey(record, true)} -> modified`)
);
diffResult["dict:remove"].map((record) =>
  console.log(`${formatKey(record, true)} -> removed`)
);
diffResult["dict:add"].map((record) =>
  console.log(`${formatKey(record, false)} -> added`)
);
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/jycm@0.2.0/dist/index.js"></script>
```